# Integrate openstreetmap in existing Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, maps, openstreetmap

I am looking for some help setting up openstreetmap in my existing rails app. I am new to the whole maps thing.
In my app i am tracking locations of vehicles. now I want to add a feature where I can get the maxspeed, name and type of a road as well. I am considering openstreetmap because I dont want to make third party api calls for every location I get as the number of locations are greater than 1M per day.

Do I need to duplicate entire schema of OSM? as there are many irrelevant tables in the schema. or simple I should parse the .osm file and create tables for nodes ways and relations only? 
Also I would need to keep this data updated.

I would really appreciate if any one can point me in the right direction.. or share some links that would help me start?

Thanks

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/57179/integrate-osm-in-existing-rails-app

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I was able to integrate OSM in slim mode in my current rails app.

`brew install osm2pgsql` // this is for mac OS, you can use the package manager of your os

`brew install postgis` // extension required for postgres

run the following commands on your database

`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;`

`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore;`

now time to migrate the data

`osm2pgsql -c -d DATABASE_NAME --slim planet.osm.pbf`

Comment: This sounds such a great workaround, do you have any post on how to get started on it? I'm planning to add delivery tracking on a Rails app and I was wondering if you can help me sharing a starting point like yours.